# Looking for an index for subjects in tanach

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

I am looking for an index for subjects in tanach. For example every place that pesach is mentioned/refered to or every time bris milah is mentioned/refered to etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following concordances for subjects in which you are interested:

1) Abraham Even Shoshan, *A New Concordance to the Bible*.

(2) Solomon Mandelkern, *Heikhal ha-Qodesh*.

(3) See also the index in the Hertz Chumash, *The Pentateuch and Haftorahs*.

Comment: @Yosef Gabriel I have added another resource. Can you give me an upvote?